# Respository for Datastage jobs

Tags: data-warehouse, datastage

We are constantly doing changes to the ETL program (IBM Datastage 8.5) and mostly in the same project folder.

There are so many versions of code which confuses the developer at the point of implementation.

What I am looking for is a GitHub thingy for datastage codes..

Can the experts please assist me...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Datastage is pretty terrible when it comes to version control. 
Different organizations use different tools to try and get some amount of version control in place. 
for example 
1. they would store the latest dsx of the code in a server.
2. and from there on use SVN to check in and check out the code. 
3. So if you need to work on a code you would first check if anyone has checked it out if not then proceed to extract the latest version of the dsx from SVN ; check out the dsx in SVN ; 
4. import and make the changes ; 
5. take the export of the changed code ; 
6. check it back in at SVN
I know its not a solution really but probably your best bet in large developer environment.

Comment: @ Ashish, Thanks for your reply. Yes that is the interim solution we are working out..  :)

Answer (score 0):

We have InfoSphere Information Server Manager and its available with DataStage installation .

- Use InfoSphere Information Server Manager to create deployment packages for
  DataStage Components .
- and get any good version control Tool to maintain versions .

Example - you can use eclipse SVN Version utility

To start this process , always get latest code from LIVE Env and make the changes in Test Env Or other Env.

before deployment -

- use InfoSphere Information Server Manager to create backup package of related DataStage component in Prod and get the version number for that from SVN
- create the package for modified jobs and send it to Live Env with out replacing the existing or running code .
- get version number for this package from SVN .

Deployment -

- Use InfoSphere Information Server Manager replace the existing code  with new one .
- Rollback the code to previous version if any problem with new deplyment

Answer (score 0):

Currently I'm using the option to export jobs as **dsx** files do versionate them.

So, when I need to rollback to an previous version, just use the import objects option and select the exported **dsx** file.

Comment: I'm doing the same, with the addition of automation-friendly command-line deployment of DSX files.

Answer (score -2):

Those following this thread might be interested to know that my organisation's solution for implementing DevOps approaches with DataStage development (called 'MettleCI') has now been announced on the Atlassian Marketplace:
  https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.datamigrators.atlassian.bitbucket.mettleci/

[MettleCI Website](https://www.mettleci.com/mettleci.html)

[Example of DataStage job in Git](https://vimeo.com/261211114)

Comment: please don't share link here